# Add nested enumerable support to custom class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, multivalue

I am currently working in Visual Studio 2015 using Visual Basic and I have a class that takes a delimited string and can extract/replace data at positions within the string, similar to a jagged array, up to three levels deep.  I may expand the class to handle deeper than three levels, but for now, I'll stick with the three.  This is exactly like a PICK mvdbms data structure for those who are familiar.  The base class to read and write the data within the class has already been built.  For space and expediency, I have included redacted code as a reference in assisting with my question.  If more data is needed, I can provide the whole class.  Also, if during the discussion of this question there are concerns or suggestions to improve my code, I am always willing to listen to constructive feedback.

The class:

```
Public Class MVString

#Region " Properties "
    Private Record As String
    Default WriteOnly Property MV(ByVal str As String) As MVString
        Set
            Record = str
        End Set
    End Property

    Default Public Property MV(ByVal AMPos As Integer) As MVString
       'Get and set value at top level
    End Property

    Default Public Property MV(ByVal AMPos As Integer, ByVal VMPos As Integer) As MVString
        'Get and set value at middle level
    End Property

    Default Public Property MV(ByVal AMPos As Integer, ByVal VMPos As Integer, ByVal SMPos As Integer) As MVString
        'Get and set value at deepest level
    End Property
#End Region

#Region " Constructors "
    Public Sub New()
        Record = ""
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal str As String)
        Record = str
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region " Methods "
    Public Sub Clear()
        Record = ""
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Record
    End Function
#End Region

#Region " Operators "
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(v As String) As MVString
        Return New MVString(v)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(v As MVString) As String
        Return v.ToString
    End Operator
#End Region

End Class
```

My question is this: How do I go about creating enumerable support for this class and limit it to the three levels so the system knows which level it is on and which delimiter it needs to use?  For example, if I have the following variable:

Dim DelimitedString As String = "Foo,4,7,1-2,,6|Bar,4,2,8-7,5,7|Fly,4,,8-7,5,7"

The delimiter for the top level would be the "|", the second level would be "," and the deepest level would be "-".  In this instance, the top level would be an array {"Foo,4,7,1-2,,6", "Bar,4,2,8-7,5,7", "Fly,4,,8-7,5,7"}, the second level would first enumerate through the first element in the upper level, and return {"Foo", "4", "7", "1-2", "", "6"}, etc...

Any ideas on where to start?

Update:

I'm Not sure how to incorporate the dictionary into the class so I've updated my post with what I had come up with before.

```
Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of String) Implements IEnumerable(Of String).GetEnumerator
    Return New MVStringEnumerator(Record)
End Function

Private Function IEnumerable_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    Return Me.GetEnumerator()
End Function

Private Class MVStringEnumerator
    Implements IEnumerator(Of String)

    Private _ThisArray() As String
    Private idx As Integer

    Public ReadOnly Property Current As String Implements IEnumerator(Of String).Current
        Get
            Return If(idx < _ThisArray.Count, _ThisArray(idx), DirectCast(Nothing, String))
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly Property IEnumerator_Current As Object Implements IEnumerator.Current
        Get
            Return Me.Current
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal record As String)
        Select Case True
            Case record.Contains("|"c)
                _ThisArray = Split(record, "|"c)
            Case record.Contains(","c)
                _ThisArray = Split(record, ","c)
            Case record.Contains("-"c)
                _ThisArray = Split(record, "-"c)
        End Select
        idx = -1
    End Sub

    Public Sub Reset() Implements IEnumerator.Reset
        idx = -1
    End Sub

    Public Function MoveNext() As Boolean Implements IEnumerator.MoveNext
        idx += 1
        If idx >= _ThisArray.Count Then Return False
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the right idea with the MVStringEnumerator, where you're ultimately enumerating an array of strings rather than a MV delimited string. (As an MVDBMS expert I understand your references.) This could be fairly simple. I'd eliminate the double duty of this task, parsing delimiters And enumeration.

First whittle the enumerated object down to the lowest level of the dynamic array desired:

`myValue = myMVString.MV(1,4)`

Second, make that enumerable:

`mySubValues = myValue.AsEnumerable()`

Last, enumerate mySubValues as a common array of strings. So the enumeration is unaware of the MV-nature of the original dynamic array.
Of course all of the above can be done more elegantly and encapsulated into a single method that returns the desired enumerable, like :

`myEnumerable = myMVString.AsEnumerable(1,4)`

Or ultimately just iterate over something like `new MyEnumerable(myMVSTRING(1,4))`.

Note that if you're actually working with a MVDBMS, each platform has its own free class libraries to do this kind of thing: MVSP, UO.NET, QMClient, etc. So you may not need to write this from scratch at all - though it is a good exercise.

**Side note**

If you are emulating MV dynamic arrays, your code uses a base index of 0 where MV uses 1.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  First, I'll reply to your side note.  Inside of my Default Properties I handle the conversion between 1-based and 0-based positioning.  Regarding your other suggestions, I may need some help since I've only been programming VB.NET for 6 months.  We are using RocketD3 so there is already the free class library; this has only been a learning exercise I gave myself to expand my understanding of VB and probably bit off more than I can chew.  Anyway, how do I whittle down to the lowest level?  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: After reviewing your answer again, I understand it better now.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Glad it made sense. Look around for C# or VB.NET examples for UO.NET. Also consider cross-posting inquiries like this to U2/MVDBMS-specific forums. And (while this usually is futile) consider asking your VAR for info.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a dictionary

```
        Dim input As String = "Foo,4,7,1-2,,6|Bar,4,2,8-7,5,7|Fly,4,,8-7,5,7"

        Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String()) = input.Split("|").Select(Function(x) x.Split(",")) _
           .GroupBy(Function(x) x(0), Function(y) y.Skip(1).ToArray()) _
           .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) y.FirstOrDefault())
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would implement the dictionary into my class so I've added what I currently have tried.

Comment: See posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216583/custom-collection-of-t